# Firebase database rest simple query not working

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying just to filter some data in firebase database.

ex:
Doing a get request on

*https://projectname.firebaseio.com/logs.json*

Will give me the next response:

```
"-KvW0jtLcytZnzIXonK6": {
    "exception": "NPE",
    "level": "Verbose",
    "message": "A message example",
    "tag": "MainActivity",
    "timestamp": "50",
    "user": "paul"
},
"-KvW0f7o-SP33k5Icx5d": {
    "exception": "NPE",
    "level": "Verbose",
    "message": "A message example",
    "tag": "MainActivity",
    "timestamp": "210",
    "user": "paul"
},
"-KvW0dPwp9eCSJqTcAWS": {
    "exception": "NPE",
    "level": "Verbose",
    "message": "A message example",
    "tag": "MainActivity",
    "timestamp": "100",
    "user": "paul"
},
```

I just want to be able to filter by the timestamp.
Example:
* query for all logs where the timestamp is greater than 90

I've tried this with

```
https://projectname.firebaseio.com/logs.json?orderBy="timestamp"&startsAt=90
```

But the result is not filtered.

Comment: Did you try `https://projectname.firebaseio.com/logs.json?orderBy="timestamp"&startAt=90`. I think it's `startAt`, not `startsAt` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. Your `timestamp` is stored as a string, so you need to pass the value for the query as a string too.
2. The parameter name is `startAt`, not `startsAt` (as ittus said in their comment).

So:

```
https://projectname.firebaseio.com/logs.json?orderBy="timestamp"&startAt="90"
```